# UnityWebRequest not calling server

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine

I have code to use UnityWebRequest to call a webserver. Debugging it revealed that it never even calls the server and always returns with 0 bytes. I have attached a debugger to my server and can see that it does not get called.

Even tried calling google and still have an empty result. These tests were done from within the unity editor.

Is there something I need to enable before I can use networking libraries?

```
void Awake() {
        StartCoroutine("CallWebserverCR");
    }

    IEnumerator CallWebserverCR()
    {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://www.google.com");
        yield return www.Send();

        if (www.isError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
            byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using this in the coroutine works though:`WWW www = new WWW(server + usersUrl);
        yield return www;

        if (www.error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(www.text);
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only difference I see between your code and Unity's example is that they have a 'using' statement:

```
IEnumerator GetText() {
    using(UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://www.my-server.com")) {
        yield return www.Send();

        if(www.isError) {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else {
            // Show results as text
            Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);

            // Or retrieve results as binary data
            byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I feel like a real tool, but for some reason things just started working when I switched back from WWW to UnityWebRequest, write this question off as a PEBKAC